# Indexing USGS Landsat Collection 2 data in Open Data Cube

Tags: landsat, usgs, open-data-cube, indexing

The [USGS Landsat Collection 2](https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-collection-2) data has been released for a while and there's no clear way to index it into the Open Data Cube.

Is there a prepare script or some other method that can be used to index this data into an ODC database so that it can be used?

Comment: this Q&A needs to be memorialized 